# C# program using a sphinx4 .jar converted to .dll fails

Tags: ikvm, sphinx4

When I try to instantiate the LiveSpeechRecognizer, it throws an error which gives the following stack trace:

```
Exception thrown: 'edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertyException' in VoiceRecognition.dll
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.AutoCepstrum.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(String instanceName)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponentList(String name, Class tclass)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(String name)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.SimpleAcousticScorer.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(String name)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstLookaheadSearchManager.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(String name)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(String name)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(PropertySheet ps)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner()
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(String instanceName)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context..ctor(String path, Configuration config)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context..ctor(Configuration config)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer..ctor(Configuration configuration)
   at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer..ctor(Configuration configuration)
   at TestingStandaloneCSVoiceRecognition.Program..ctor()
```

I"ve been trying to sift through the documentation and code to figure out what's causing it, but I've had little luck so far. I should probably note that I used IKVM to convert the .jars to a .dll which I've imported into a Visual Studio C# project. The LiveSpeechRecognizer doesn't even finish instantiating before throwing the error. I've made sure that I've imported all dependencies, so that's not the issue. The java program works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to call java code from C#, instead you can simply use pocketsphinx dll with C# API, see

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/swig/csharp

Comment: I've been working on trying to do that, but I'm struggling to get swig working right.

Comment: What is your problem with swig exactly?

Comment: I just don't know how to use it yet I think. I'm using windows, and the .exe provided for use with windows doesn't do anything.